# XSL If condition : test any child node attribute containing a String

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML structure that I'm currently dealing with :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D attribute1="testAttr1" attribute2="testAttr2"/>
            <D attribute1="testAttr1_2" attribute2="testAttr2_2"/>
            <D attribute1="testAttr1_3" attribute2="testAttr2_3"/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

I haveto write `XSL:if` condition which should be passed if **any of the** D child nodes **attribute2** contains a string "Attr" something like below :

```
<xsl:if test="contains(A/B/C/*D/@attribute2,'Attr')">

</xsl:if>
```

Above condition isn't working. If I remove * and try `xsl:if test="contains(A/B/C/D/@attribute2,'Attr')"` It will work only if first D child **attribute2** contains the given String.
How to make it work even if any of the D child **attribute2** contains the string ( say 2nd D or 3rd) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. `<xsl:if test="//D[contains(@attribute2, 'Attr')]">` or `<xsl:if test="//D/@attribute2[contains(., 'Attr')]">`.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks. Is there any easy way to check the string in above statement case insensitive  way?

Comment: In XSLT 2/3 with built-in regular expression support, yes, e.g. `//D[matches(@attribute2, 'attr', 'i')]`, some XSLT 1 processors also provide extension function support for regular expressions, in XSLT 1 you can use `translate` e.g. `..<xsl:param name="upper-case-letters">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:param><xsl:param name="lower-case-letters">abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz</xsl:param>.. <xsl:if test="//D[contains(translate(@attribute2, $upper-case-letters, $lower-case-letters), 'attr')]">..`.